# Django Rendering Order

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I am having trouble getting Django to render the page in the order I want and am hoping someone can explain (maybe conceptually) what I need to do (or understand) to correct the issue.

Here's how my template (.html) is structured:

```
{% extend nav_pane %}

{% block body_block %}

<some HTML>

{% stuff from views.py (for loop) %}

<footer HTML>

{% endblock %}
```

This is how the template renders:

```
nav_pane - OK at Top

<some HTML>

<footer HTML> -- This jumps over model data from view.py

model data from view.py -- appears on the bottom??
```

I've tried putting the footer HTML in a separate block, but it still jumps over the model data being send in from views.py

Obviously, I am new to Django, so there may be some fundamental concept I'm missing about the order templates render information...

Any tips/techniques/references on controlling how things appear in the browser are appreciated.

Comment: Another possibility is that your css style somehow messed up so visually footer html is on top of model data. You could verify this by checking the source html code from browser and see if the model data is before footer.

Comment: This appears to be a question about HTML and CSS, and nothing to do with Django.

Comment: Where do you have your block in your base template? Maybe you are putting it in some block that is at the bottom on the parent template.

Comment: I am using Bootstrap in the html/css.

Comment: I am using Bootstrap in the html/css, not 100% sure how that will effect the order it renders. Looking at the render timeline is also kind of difficult - it's very busy.